# App Engine datastore query, to many Indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a form with 7 input fields. each of these fields should query for a bigger and/or smaller value and every field could be empty or not. As inequality filters work only on one property, I wanted to make an array of int's property, that contains up to 20 integers and query it with a 'Property =' filter to check if the value is present in the given array. However, this gives me the message 'too many indexed properties'.

Im bit lost as i can't use inequality filters on more than one property and list-properties create to many indexes.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: yeah, look at SQL instead ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use CloudSql or Full Text Search for this kind of complex querying. In particular, you're going to face a lot of challenges if you need to include ordering for these queries, as you'll need explicit multiproperty indexes set up then. You will then face a combinatorial explosion problem.